# How to deactivate the cascading saving in Doctrine 2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, one-to-many, many-to-one, persist

I have Entities `Foo` and `Bar` with a bidirectional `ManyToOne` relationship:

```
/**
 * Foo
 *
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="foo",
 *     indexes={
 *         ...
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     ...
 * })
 */
class Foo extends AbstractDataObject
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @var Bar
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bar")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bar_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    protected $bar;
    ...
}

/**
 * Bar
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="bar")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Bar extends AbstractDataObject
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;
    ...
}
```

When I now try to save a `Foo` entity like this:

```
$this->entityManager->persist($foo);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

I get a `Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException`:

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'MyNamespace\DataObject\Foo#bar' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity:
MyNamespace\DataObject\Bar@000000006098ccff0000000068c23676.
To solve this issue:
    Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity
    or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).
If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'MyNamespace\DataObject\Bar#__toString()' to get a clue.
```

I don't want the `Foo#$bar` to be automatically saved with the `Foo`. Otherwise I would define the `@ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"})`.

**Why does Doctrine save though there is no `cascade={"persist"}` defined?**

**How to avoid this behavior and just save the top level entity (here: `Foo`) without its related entities?**

Comment: Surprised that someone with your reps would think that asking the same question repeatedly would be an effective strategy on stackoverflow.  This will be marked as an exact duplicate shortly.

Comment: The question duplicates a question from a comment, but it's OK.

Comment: From the [Doctrine doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html) on `cascade`: "New entities in a collection not marked as `cascade: persist` will produce an Exception and rollback the flush() operation."